# SELECT sum of column B based on distinct prefix of column A

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get a sum of the Quantity column where the first 3 characters of the Account column are distinct. 
Here's what I'm trying to get to:

```
111total   222total   333total
30         10         50
```

...etc

Here's an example of what my data looks like:

```
Account        Quantity
111000000      12
111000001      15
111000002      3
222000001      5
222000002      5
333000001      10
333000002      20
333000003      20
```

Assuming that account list has too many distinct values to define each individually like:

```
SUM(table.Quantity) as 111total,
SUM(table.Quantity) as 222total, 
SUM(table.Quantity) as 333total
```

etc, what would the proper syntax be; I'm having trouble incorporating the latter part I have to define DISTINCT with my LEFT(Account, 3).  I tried a few variations, but not knowing how to define the first part hinders my ability to test the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a group by clause instead of DISTINCT

```
SELECT LEFT(Account,3) AccountPrefix, SUM(qty) sumOfQty 
FROM myTable
GROUP BY LEFT(Account,3)
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I didn't know you could just say "AccountPrefix" without saying "as AccountPrefix" either, interesting.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will give you what you want:

```
SELECT LEFT(Account,3) as AccountPrefix, SUM(Quantity) AS total
FROM Table
GROUP BY LEFT(Account,3)
```

Comment: Kevin gets the juice because he was a minute earlier, but in my heart, I accepted your answer too.  Rejoice.